# Two threads kept running without completed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, alternate

I'm trying to get the result below running 2 threads alternately. *Thread `A` prints `Step 1` and `Step 3` and thread `B` prints `Step 2` and `Step 4` (I use **Python 3.8.5**):

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
```

So, with global variables, locks and while statements, I created the code below to try to get the result above:

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

flow = "Step 1"

def test1():
    global flow
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 1":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 2"
                lock.release()
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 3":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 4"
                lock.release()
                break
            break

def test2():
    global flow
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 2":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 3"
                lock.release()
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 4":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                lock.release()
                break
            break

t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

But, the code above got the result below without `Step 3` and `Step 4`, then the program kept running without completed. *Thread `A` printed `Step 1`, then thread `B` printed `Step 2`, then the program kept running without printing `Step 3` and `Step 4`:

```
Step 1
Step 2
```

I couldn't find any mistakes so how can I get the proper result with `Step 3` and `Step 4`? And, why did I get the result without `Step 3` and `Step 4`?

Comment: For others coming to this Q&A because of the tags or title: This issue has nothing to do with threading, multiprocessing, concurrency ("alternation") or even a specific Python version. It's just an unconditional `break` due to indenting it once too much (i.e. a typo).

Answer (score -1):

In both second while loops you have an extra `break` that terminates the execution after first run. (outside the `if`-block). And you have also souperflous extra outside-while loops.

```
def test1():
    global flow
    while True: # <--- DELETE ME
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 1":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 2"
                lock.release()
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 3":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 4"
                lock.release()
                break
            break # <--- DELETE ME
```

---

However, you are reading the `flow` outside of the lock state. In an real world application this could case an error, as the variable can change between the `if` and the `lock`. Thus, this code is NOT really THREADSAFE even with the lock.

Comment: This code – once its break conditions are fixed – is perfectly thread safe. While assigning and reading for comparison are not mutually atomic, `flow` will always have a well-defined value. The worst that can happen is one single superfluous spin-lock iteration; seeing how spin-locking is superfluous to begin with, that doesn't make the code any worse.

Comment: Yes, in this special case, it is by chance. However, this looks like a demo/boild down example. The locked part does not do too much, and the other thread would happily wait for the lock once the condition is true and the other has not released it yet. 
Adding more logic, changing the threat composition, ... and this code might break. Thus, the warning. Threadding is anything but trivial.

Answer (score -2):

The position of each last `break` in `test1()` and `test2()` is wrong so you need to put each last `break` just in the outer `while` statement as shown below:

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

flow = "Step 1"

def test1():
    global flow
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 1":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 2"
                lock.release()
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 3":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 4"
                lock.release()
                break
        break # This breaks the outer "while" statement

def test2():
    global flow
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 2":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                flow = "Step 3"
                lock.release()
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow == "Step 4":
                lock.acquire()
                print(flow)
                lock.release()
                break
        break # # This breaks the outer "while" statement

t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Then, you can get the proper result below:

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
```